How can i parse string nested json with Nifi?
I have a JSON data in the ClickHouse database with a type of string. The JSON data looks like this:
[{ "Name": "Gta V" "Type": "Xyz" "content": "{"Game":{"Subject":[{"Time":{"@value":"201511021057"}}]}}" }]

The output I get using Nifi ExecuteSqlRecord is like this. I can remove the \ character using the ReplaceText process. The output looks like this:
[{ "Name": "Gta V" "Type": "Xyz" "content": "{"Game":{"Subject":[{"Time":{"@value":"201511021057"}}]}}" }]

However, the value part for the content key is still a string. How can I make its type as JSON?
The desired output is like this:
[{ "Name": "Gta V" "Type": "Xyz" "content": {"Game":{"Subject":[{"Time":{"@value":"201511021057"}}]}} }]

